# Get sums of pairs of elements in a numpy array

Tags: python, numpy, scipy

I have an array:

```
t = [4, 5, 0, 7, 1, 6, 8, 3, 2, 9]
```

which is just a random shuffle of the range [0, 9]. I need to calculate this:

```
t2 = [9, 5, 7, 8, 7, 14, 11, 5, 11, 13]
```

which is just:

```
t2 = [t[0]+t[1], t[1]+t[2], t[2]+t[3], t[3]+t[4], ..., t[9]+t[0]]
```

Is there a way I can do this with numpy to avoid a python for loop when dealing with large arrays?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

You could take advantage of a NumPy array's ability to sum element-wise:

```
In [5]: import numpy as np

In [6]: t = np.array([4, 5, 0, 7, 1, 6, 8, 3, 2, 9])

In [7]: t + np.r_[t[1:],t[0]]
Out[7]: array([ 9,  5,  7,  8,  7, 14, 11,  5, 11, 13])
```

[np.r_](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.r_.html) is one way to concatenate sequences together to form a new numpy array. As we'll see below, it turns out not to be the best way *in this case*.

---

Another possibility is:

```
In [10]: t + np.roll(t,-1)
Out[10]: array([ 9,  5,  7,  8,  7, 14, 11,  5, 11, 13])
```

It appears using [`np.roll`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.roll.html) is significantly faster:

```
In [11]: timeit t + np.roll(t,-1)
100000 loops, best of 3: 17.2 us per loop

In [12]: timeit t + np.r_[t[1:],t[0]]
10000 loops, best of 3: 35.5 us per loop
```

Comment: Had to Google what `np.r_` does :) Could you add the link and a brief explanation to the answer?

Answer (score 1):

You can do this pretty happily with [`zip()`](http://docs.python.org/library/functions.html#zip), a list slice, and [a list comprehension](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=t85uBptTDYY):

```
t2 = [a+b for (a, b) in zip(t, t[1:])]
t2.append(t[0]+t[-1])
```

We need the extra `append()` to add in the last element, as `zip()` only works until the shortest iterator ends. A list comprehension is significantly faster than a normal `for` loop as it's implemented C-side in Python, rather than as a Python loop.

The alternative is to use [`itertools.zip_longest`](http://docs.python.org/release/3.0.1/library/itertools.html#itertools.zip_longest):

```
from itertools import zip_longest
t2 = [a+b for (a, b) in zip_longest(t, t[1:], fillvalue=t[0])]
```

To fill the extra value in. Do note that this function is [`itertools.izip_longest`](http://docs.python.org/library/itertools.html#itertools.izip_longest) in Python 2.x.

Comment: The author specifically asked to solve the task **with numpy** to avoid Python loop overhead.

Comment: @ovgolovin No, he asked to avoid a python loop, and a list comprehension is done as a loop in C within Python. This means it's significantly faster than a normal loop.

Comment: It will still incredibly suboptimal compared to Numpy vector operations.

Comment: Please, reflect it in the answer. Because I think the reason why list comprehension is used is more important than the technical implementation details of the list comprehension.

Comment: Oops, I posted the exact same answer without realizing it. I'm deleting mine.

Comment: @larsmans I'm not saying it's the optimal solution with numpy involved, merely that it is a solution that is faster than a for loop. Just because it's not the best answer, doesn't make it not a valid answer.

Comment: @Lattyware: the OP explicitly wants to "do this with numpy". For a Numpy user, a list comprehension == a Python loop.

Comment: @larsmans I think it's OK to have this answer too. But it should be clearly reflected what are the upsides and the downsides of this solution.

Comment: I guess I should have been more clear in my question. I wanted to avoid looping and try to use numpy's vector operations.

Comment: @larsmans I'm pretty sure that 'with numpy' was an edit, I believe when I posted it said 'avoiding a for loop' (before anyone says there are no edits, there is a grace period where edits don't show). I think there is enough value to this answer that leaving it up won't cause anyone any harm, and might be interesting to someone. There are very clear warnings in the comments that this is a slower solution than the above, if the higher score doesn't tell people.

Comment: @Lattyware **with numpy** was from the very beginning. But the fact that OP does want `numpy` implementation doesn't mean that this answer can't come in handy to somebody who will face the same problem and will find this question here.

Comment: I'm not going to argue over the "with numpy" part and I undid the downvote.

Answer (score 1):

What about

```
import numpy as np
t = np.array([4, 5, 0, 7, 1, 6, 8, 3, 2, 9])

new_t = t + np.hstack((t[1:], [t[0]]))
```

Result:

```
>>> new_t
array([ 9,  5,  7,  8,  7, 14, 11,  5, 11, 13])
```

Comment: +1 for another solution, although it is a little slower than the accepted answer.