# Why doesn't scipy's interpolate average over colocated values?

Tags: python, arrays, scipy, interpolation

If I were to run the following code:

```
>>> from scipy.interpolate import interpolate
>>> import numpy as np
>>> data = np.arange(10)
>>> times = np.r_[np.arange(5),np.arange(5)]
>>> new_times = np.arange(5)
>>> f = interpolate.interp1d(times,data)
>>> interp_data = f(new_times)
```

I would naively (and hopefully) expect the following:

```
>>> interp_data
array([2.5,  3.5,  4.5,  5.5,  6.5])
```

based on the assumption that colocated values would be averaged and weighted accordingly in the interpolation. But, in fact, the result is:

```
>>> interp_data               
array([ 0.,  6.,  7.,  8.,  9.])
```

What is causing this behaviour, and how could it be rectified?

Answer (score 1):

From the `interp1d` documentation:

> assume_sorted : bool, optional If False, values of x can be in any
>   order and they are sorted first. If True, x has to be an array of
>   monotonically increasing values.

I can only get the result you got by explicity forcing `assume_sorted` to be `True`:

```
>>> f = interpolate.interp1d(times,data, assume_sorted=True)
>>> interp_data = f(new_times)
>>> interp_data
array([ 0.,  6.,  7.,  8.,  9.])
```

It appears from your code that `assume_sorted` defaulted to `True`, which is giving the answer you don't expect.

If you explicitly set it to `False`, according to the documentation, `interp1d` sorts it automatically, and then does the interpolation, giving

```
>>> f = interpolate.interp1d(times,data)
>>> interp_data = f(new_times)
>>> interp_data
array([ nan,   1.,   2.,   3.,   4.])
```

which is consistent with the documentation.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure exact what you want but it seems interp may not be the best way to achieve this. An interpolation function, f, should relate a single input to a single output, i.e.

```
from scipy.interpolate import interpolate
import numpy as np
data = np.arange(2.,8.)
times = np.arange(data.shape[0])
new_times = np.arange(0.5,5.,1.)
f = interpolate.interp1d(times,data)
interp_data = f(new_times)
```

Alternatively, maybe an answer like:
[Get sums of pairs of elements in a numpy array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10366665/get-sums-of-pairs-of-elements-in-a-numpy-array)
may be what you wanted?

Answer (score 0):

No, `interp1d` would not weight, average or do anything else to the data for you.

It expects the data to be sorted. If your scipy is recent enough (0.14 or above), it has `assume_sorted` keyword which you can set to False and then it'll just sort it for you. The precise behavior for unsorted data is undefined.